# Is there a way to have an Argparse argument imply multiple other options?

Tags: python, argparse

I have 2 options, that can take various arguments. I want to have a special option that means "both of those with specific standard data". This will be a different mode then the operation with no arguments.

```
    parser.add_argument('--use-std-date', '-U', action='store_const',
                        const=nominal_test_fixture_day, dest='use_date')
    parser.add_argument('--use-date', '-u', action='store', type=parse_date,
                        metavar='%Y-%m-%d', dest='use_date', nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument('--write-out-data', '-w', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-build-standerd-data', help="This option implies both '--use-std-date', and '--write-out-data'")
```

In my dream world, there would be something like:

```
parser.add_argument('--build-standerd-data', implies="-U -w")
```

and if the parser got `--build-standerd-data` it would recurse the `"-U -w"` back into `parse_args()` and add the results to the return.  It would probably also do something smart if it got both `--build-standerd-data` and `--use-std-date` (ignore one? raise error?).

Does anything like this exist or do I just need to add a mess of if-else statements to the my main function?

Comment: You don't get extra points for implementing interactions like this within `argparse` (if possible).  Post-parsing processing in your own code is allowed.  Your first priority is to understand what the user wants (parsing).  Sometimes you can implement argument interactions in custom `Action` subclasses, but that just puts that 'mess of if/else' in the `__call__` method.  It doesn't save you from writing that logic.

Comment: your user could chain '-U' and '-w', e.g. '-Uw'

Comment: If '-u' had `nargs='?', you could get a 3 way input, with `default`, `const`, and user specified.

Comment: Nitpick, but "standerd" -> "standard"